# Spring integration DSL creating Sftp OutBound Adapter in java 1.7

Tags: spring-integration

I have created a Sftp outbound flow in spring DSL also I have created one more File inbound flow on top of the Sftp outbound flow for look up files from my local directory and send it to the Message channel which is responsible for copying the file to the remote directory but when I am running my code no file is getting copied in remote directory. So I am getting stuck in this point, Can any one please provide any pointer to it as I am not able to proceed.

This is my session Factory...

```
    @Autowired
    private DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory;

    @Bean
    public DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(
                true);
        factory.setHost("111.11.12.143");
        factory.setPort(22);
        factory.setUser("sftp");
        factory.setPassword("*******");         
        return factory;
    }
```

This is my sftp outbound flow..

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sftpOutboundFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("toSftpChannel")
                .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(this.sftpSessionFactory)
                        .remoteFileSeparator("\\")
                        .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                        .remoteDirectory(remDir)).get();
    }
```

This is my File inbound flow..

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileReadingFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(fileMessageSource(),
                         new Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec>() {

                    @Override
                    public void accept(SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec e) {
                        e.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(6));
                    }
                })
                .transform(Transformers.fileToByteArray())
                .channel(MessageChannels.queue("fileReadingResultChannel"))
                .get();
    }
```

This the MessageSource method.......

```
    @Bean
    public MessageSource<File> fileMessageSource() {

        FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        source.setDirectory(new File(localDir));
        source.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        System.out.println("enter fileMessageSource....."+ source.receive());
        return source;
    }
```

This is my Junit Test method...

```
@Autowired
private DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("toSftpChannel")
private MessageChannel toSftpChannel;

@Autowired  
@Qualifier("fileReadingResultChannel")
private PollableChannel fileReadingResultChannel;

@Test
public void testSftpOutboundFlow() {        
    Message<?> message = ((PollableChannel) fileReadingResultChannel)
            .receive(600);
    System.out.println("message....."+message);     
    this.toSftpChannel.send(message);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `System.out.println("enter fileMessageSource....."+ source.receive());` is bad in the `fileMessageSource()` `@Bean`, just because you do there `source.receive()`. It isn't responsibility of `SOUT` to do that.

From other side it would be better if you'd share with us some StackTrace on the matter...

And one more point: do you see in console the result of `System.out.println("message....."+message);` ?

Comment: The 'message' is coming null when there is only one file in my local directory, but if there are more than than one  file its picking only the 2nd file and copy it over the remote directory then stop processing. Please find the StackTrace for the same  ...............................enter fileMessageSource.....GenericMessage [payload=D:\local_copy\SFTP.TXT, headers={timestamp=1436937421367, id=37994faa-236c-b64f-6390-f496bebb6a19}]
message.....null             . This time I have kept only one file and the message is coming null.

Comment: Hi Artem,  I have removed the System.out.println("enter fileMessageSource....."+ source.receive());  from fileMessageSource() method. Now the 1st file is geeting copied in remote machine but other files are not copied. I think the poller is not working properly but not sure. Can you please give some pointer on this.

Comment: That's just because your test-case takes care only about the first file and exits.

Comment: Thanks Artem, Can I handle this in a while loop in my Test method? like this....@Test
 public void testSftpOutboundFlow() {
  while(!fileReadingResultChannel.equals(null)){
   Message<?> message = this.fileReadingResultChannel.receive(60000);
   this.toSftpChannel.send(message);   
  }
 }

Comment: Yes, you can. Or just make as much `fileReadingResultChannel.receive()` manually as file you'd like to test.

Comment: Hi Artem, I have added the above mentioned while loop and it works but after successfully sending all the files to the remote system, the same files are not deleted from my local folder so it goes to a infinite loop and my Junit test fails, so can you please give some pointer on this.

Comment: Deleted? It's exactly the separate question. Although you can use for that `.transactionSynchronizationFactory()`. From other side you should supply `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` to your `FileReadingMessageSource`. It is done by default only since Spring Integration 4.2 -  https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3718

Comment: Hi Artem, I have supplied AcceptOnceFileListFilter  to my FileReadingMessageSource, but any way duplicate file were not copied earlier also but I need to delete those all files from my local directory as 'while(fileReadingResultChannel != null) '  should satisfy, because I need to break my loop. I could not able to use '.transactionSynchronizationFactory()'. Could you please provide any sample to use .transactionSynchronizationFactory() method.

Comment: You can find the XML config for that here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-file/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/file/config/FileInboundChannelAdapterParserTests-context.xml